# How to split different texts using multiple REGEX rules and keep original text origin information in R

Tags: regex, r, text, text-mining

Have a character vector of different texts. I want to apply on each multiple REGEX split rules. However I do want to also keep/know the original texts delimitations. Maybe by creating a list of character vectors, where each list entry is one element of the original vector.

suppose the character vector is:

```
texts <- c("Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV täglichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ./$. In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR Büchern/NN gefüllt/VVPP ,/$, jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA Stück/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN ./$. Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lässt/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$, dank/APPR der/ART Form/NN ,/$, besonders/ADV für/APPR Bücher/NN und/KON Schreibutensilien/NN ideal/ADJD nutzen/VVINF ./$. Wer/PWS es/PPER bei/APPR der/ART Beladung/NN -LRB-/TRUNC wie/KOKOM ich/PPER regelmäßig/ADJD -RRB-/TRUNC übertreibt/VVFIN wird/VAFIN aber/ADV schnell/ADJD merken/VVINF ,/$, dass/KOUS das/ART Tragesystem/NN Komfortgrenzen/NN hat/VAFIN -LRB-/TRUNC keine/PIAT Verstärkungsschalung/NN wie/KOKOM z.B./NN bei/APPR Wanderrucksäcken/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ./$. Bei/APPR normalem/ADJA Einsatz/NN lässt/VVFIN sich/PRF der/ART Berkeley/NE dank/APPR der/ART breiten/ADJA Trageriemen/NN aber/ADV angenehm/ADJD tragen/VVINF ./$. Die/ART Reißverschlüsse/NN bei/APPR meinem/PPOSAT Modell/NN sind/VAFIN noch/ADV vollständig/ADJD vernickelt/VVPP oder/KON verchromt/VVPP ./$. Wie/PWAV gut/ADJD die/ART neuen/ADJA Zipper/NN sind/VAFIN kann/VMFIN ich/PPER also/ADV nicht/PTKNEG beurteilen/VVINF ./$. Die/ART Verarbeitungsqualität/NN ist/VAFIN großartig/ADJD ./$. Nach/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN ist/VAFIN jetzt/ADV eine/ART Naht/NN am/APPRART Boden/NN aufgerieben/VVPP ,/$, so/ADV dass/KOUS ich/PPER langsam/ADJD einen/ART neuen/ADJA brauche/VVFIN ./$. Ansonsten/ADV hat/VAFIN mich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA Stück/NN nie/ADV im/APPRART Stich/NN gelassen/VVPP -LRB-/TRUNC vielleicht/ADV lasse/VVFIN ich/PPER das/PDS auch/ADV einfach/ADV nähen/VVFIN .../$( -RRB-/TRUNC ./$. ",
"Mir/PPER dient/VVFIN dieser/PDAT Rucksack/NN seit/APPR Jahren/NN ./$. Zunächst/ADV als/APPR Wickeltasche/NN :/$. -RRB-/TRUNC -LRB-/TRUNC wie/KOKOM bereits/ADV in/APPR einer/ART anderen/ADJA Rezension/NN erwähnt/VVPP ,/$, bietet/VVFIN dieser/PDAT Rucksack/NN genügend/PIAT Platz/NN für/APPR alles/PIS ,/$, was/PRELS das/ART Baby/NN unterwegs/ADV braucht/VVFIN und/KON sieht/VVFIN nicht/PTKNEG so/ADV schrullig/ADJD aus/PTKVZ wie/KOKOM die/ART meisten/PIDAT Wickeltaschen/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ./$. Ausserdem/NN nutze/VVFIN ich/PPER den/ART Rucksack/NN immer/ADV wieder/ADV bei/APPR Ausflügen/NN ./$. Da/KOUS ich/PPER ein/ART Problem/NN mit/APPR der/ART Wirbelsäule/NN habe/VAFIN und/KON Umhängetaschen/ADJA Gift/NN für/APPR meinen/PPOSAT Rücken/NN sind/VAFIN ,/$, ist/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN bei/APPR besonders/ADV schwerem/ADJA Inhalt/NN das/ART einzig/ADJD Wahre/NN ./$. -LRB-/TRUNC Denn/KON wer/PWS will/VMFIN schon/ADV mit/APPR einem/ART Trolley/NN zur/APPRART Uni/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ./$. Damit/PROAV ist/VAFIN eine/ART weitere/ADJA Nutzungsmöglichkeit/NN angesprochen/VVPP :/$. Ein/ART Notebook/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 15/CARD Zoll/NN -RRB-/TRUNC findet/VVFIN wunderbar/ADJD Platz/NN im/APPRART hinteren/ADJA Fach/NN ,/$, man/PIS kann/VMFIN sich/PRF für/APPR Selbiges/NN eine/ART leichte/ADJA schützende/ADJA Hülle/NN z.B./NN von/APPR ednet/ADJD ./$. kaufen/VVINF ,/$, dann/ADV ist/VAFIN perfekter/ADJA Schutz/NN gewährleistet/VVPP ./$. Der/ART entscheidende/ADJA Vorteil/NN im/APPRART Vergleich/NN zu/APPR normalen/ADJA Notebookrucksäcken/NN ist/VAFIN der/ART ,/$, dass/KOUS man/PIS ein/ART weiteres/ADJA separates/ADJA geräumiges/ADJA Fach/NN für/APPR einen/ART dicken/ADJA -LRB-/TRUNC !/$. -RRB-/TRUNC Ordner/NN oder/KON jede/PIDAT Menge/NN Bücher/NN aus/APPR der/ART Bib/NN hat/VAFIN ./$. Wer/PWS also/ADV Magister/NN -/$( oder/KON Diplomarbeit/NN schreiben/VVINF möchte/VMFIN ,/$, wird/VAFIN sich/PRF über/APPR diesen/PDAT Rucksack/NN freuen/VVINF können/VMFIN ,/$, für/APPR die/ART Dissertation/NN muss/VMFIN dann/ADV vielleicht/ADV doch/ADV noch/ADV ein/ART Trolley/NN her/PTKVZ :/$. -RRB-/TRUNC Noch/ADV ein/ART Vorzug/NN -LRB-/TRUNC für/APPR den/ART Urlaub/NN in/APPR Neapel/NE -RRB-/TRUNC :/$. Die/ART Reissverschlüsse/NN sind/VAFIN mit/APPR normalen/ADJA Vorhängeschlössern/NN verschließbar/ADJD ,/$, das/PDS macht/VVFIN es/PPER dem/ART Straßendieb/NN zumindest/ADV mal/ADV schwieriger/ADJD ,/$, denn/KON mal/ADV eben/ADV öffnen/VVINF und/KON reingreifen/VVINF ist/VAFIN nicht/PTKNEG ./$. -LRB-/TRUNC Den/ART Schlüssel/NN sollte/VMFIN man/PIS dann/ADV natürlich/ADV nicht/PTKNEG vor/APPR dem/ART Schließen/NN der/ART Schlösser/NN in/APPR den/ART Rucksack/NN stecken/VVFIN -RRB-/TRUNC Mir/PPER gefällt/VVFIN auch/ADV ,/$, dass/KOUS der/ART Rucksack/NN ,/$, wenn/KOUS man/PIS sein/PPOSAT ganzes/ADJA Volumen/NN gerade/ADV nicht/PTKNEG nutzt/VVFIN ,/$, seitlich/ADJD so/ADV zusammengezogen/VVPP werden/VAINF kann/VMFIN ,/$, dass/KOUS er/PPER nicht/PTKNEG völlig/ADJD schlaff/ADJD und/KON ausgebeult/ADJD in/APPR der/ART Gegend/NN rumhängt/VVFIN ./$. Wer/PWS ein/ART größeres/ADJA Kind/NN hat/VAFIN ,/$, kann/VMFIN für/APPR es/PPER diesen/PDAT Rucksack/NN in/APPR der/ART Variante/NN Berkeley/NE S/XY kaufen/VVINF ./$. Obwohl/KOUS ich/PPER öfter/ADV mal/ADV durch/APPR den/ART Regen/NN laufe/VVFIN ,/$, ist/VAFIN drinnen/ADV eigentlich/ADV nichts/PIS nass/ADJD geworden/VAPP ./$. -LRB-/TRUNC Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN es/PPER aber/ADV nicht/PTKNEG stundenlang/ADJD ausprobiert/VVPP -RRB-/TRUNC meine/PPOSAT Empfehlung/NN :/$. Kaufen/NN !/$. ",
"Hat/VAFIN sich/PRF gelohnt/VVPP ,/$, ihn/PPER zu/PTKZU kaufen/VVINF ./$. Für/APPR Bücher/NN und/KON Mappen/NN in/APPR der/ART Schule/NN bestens/ADV geeignet/VVPP aber/KON auch/ADV als/APPR Tagesrucksack/NN ,/$, vor/APPR allem/PIS bei/APPR Stadtausflügen/NN ,/$, wo/PWAV die/ART Einkäufe/NN darin/PROAV verschwinden/VVFIN ,/$, ein/ART Toppteil/NN ./$. Super/ADJD ist/VAFIN der/ART ausreichend/ADJD lange/ADJA Bauchriemen/NN ,/$, auch/ADV für/APPR korpulentere/ADJA Menschen/NN geeignet/VVPP ./$. ")
```

I managed to do all in one step - but I would like to use more complex rules and keep readability, be more flexible:

```
textsList <- lapply(texts,
                    function(x) strsplit(as.character(x),
                                         "(?<=und/KON)\\s(?!\\S+/V)|(?<=oder/KON)\\s|(?<=/\\$[[:punct:]])\\s(?!dass/KOUS)(?!dann/ADV)(?!weil/KOUS)",
                                         perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] "Ich/PPER habe/VAFIN meinen/PPOSAT Berkeley/NN jetzt/ADV seit/APPR 11/CARD Jahren/NN im/APPRART fast/ADV täglichen/ADJA Einsatz/NN ./$."                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [2] "In/APPR der/ART Schule/NN und/KON"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [3] "im/APPRART Studium/NN war/VAFIN der/ART Rucksack/NN meistens/ADV bis/APPR zum/APPRART bersten/ADJA mit/APPR Büchern/NN gefüllt/VVPP ,/$,"                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [4] "jetzt/ADV benutze/VVFIN ich/PPER das/ART gute/ADJA Stück/NN auf/APPR dem/ART Weg/NN zur/APPRART Arbeit/NN ./$."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [5] "Das/ART Volumen/NN -LRB-/TRUNC 30/CARD Liter/NN -RRB-/TRUNC ist/VAFIN enorm/ADJD und/KON lässt/VVFIN sich/PRF ,/$,"

 ...

 [[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "Hat/VAFIN sich/PRF gelohnt/VVPP ,/$,"                                                                          
[2] "ihn/PPER zu/PTKZU kaufen/VVINF ./$."                                                                           
[3] "Für/APPR Bücher/NN und/KON"                                                                                    
[4] "Mappen/NN in/APPR der/ART Schule/NN bestens/ADV geeignet/VVPP aber/KON auch/ADV als/APPR Tagesrucksack/NN ,/$,"
[5] "vor/APPR allem/PIS bei/APPR Stadtausflügen/NN ,/$,"                                                            
[6] "wo/PWAV die/ART Einkäufe/NN darin/PROAV verschwinden/VVFIN ,/$,"                                               
[7] "ein/ART Toppteil/NN ./$."                                                                                      
[8] "Super/ADJD ist/VAFIN der/ART ausreichend/ADJD lange/ADJA Bauchriemen/NN ,/$,"                                  
[9] "auch/ADV für/APPR korpulentere/ADJA Menschen/NN geeignet/VVPP ./$."
```

Comment: @zx81 Thank you. What I'm looking for is something like a `c("REGEXsplitcond1","REGEXsplitcond2","REGEXsplitcond3")`.

Comment: FYI added section about saving the delimiters.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can pull out all the punctuation in the text vector with   `gsub("[^[:punct:]]", "", texts)`

Answer (score 1):

In my view you are nearly there, your use of lookarounds to split the string is great.

To me it seems there two main questions.

**A. Saving the Delimiters**

One way to save the delimiters as you split is to split in two steps. Instead of splitting, replace then match all:

1. Replace your delimiters with something distinctive like >>>DELIMITER{original delimiter}<<<
2. Match all (instead of splitting) where Group 1 will capture `{original delimiter}` and Group 2 captures the match you want.

**B. Maintainance and Readability**

How about

1. storing each delimiter sub-expression in an array... so you can comment each line / rule...
2. joining the replace regex (which replaces the delimiters) with `|` in code when you need it.

That way it's readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you :) Is it possible to offer some code which works on the offered vector with the give rules?